# rand() gives values which are very close to each other

Tags: c

I am using GCC 4.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.3. All was working well till I updated it. I have absolutely no idea why it no longer works.

The problem is as follows:

`rand()` gives me back values which are extremely close to eachother, but not equal. So, upon running the program several times I get answers like.

The output of:

```
(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX.
```

```
0.945264,
0.945295,
0.945335
```

(The difference gets larger when more time has passed.)
I seed it using `srand(time(NULL));`, and it was working well till just an hour ago when I updated it. I have now tested it 20 times, and all the outputs are approx. the same, this is certainly NOT random.
Any ideas?
**EDIT**

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
main() 
{ 
 srand(time(NULL)); 
 printf("%f",(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX); 
}
```

(This is all my code, sorry I suck with formatting.)

Comment: Please post a [**minimal** test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Until I updated my compiler, gcc.

Comment: How many times do you seed it?

Comment: If you want a double, you should use [drand48](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/drand48.3.html).

Comment: I know that I also could use drand48, and I am thinking about using that, but I want to understand why this function no longer works as it is supposed to work. By the way, I seed it only once.

Comment: The C `rand` function (more precisely the common implementations of it) is an horror from the last century full of historical tragedies. Please forget about it, and use a correct random number generator in almost all cases. A good starting point is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift

Comment: @ClausW - What version of gcc were you using? I have a machine with gcc 4.0.1, so if you post a short piece of code, that compiles, I could try it.

Comment: A *good* starting point is any MT implementation. C++ has it in std libs, C should have a library available out there.

Comment: Hmmm ... `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <time.h>` and use only 1 cast (the compiler will convert the other value automagically): `rand() / (double)RAND_MAX`

Comment: What's the output of the line `printf("%f %f %f\n", (double)RAND_MAX, 1.0 + RAND_MAX, 1.0 / RAND_MAX);` (assume all necessary includes)?

Answer (score 0):

This may be another possbility:

I think it is your placement of your `srand`

When I post this

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
main() 
{ 
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){ 
        srand(time(NULL)); 
        printf("%f\n",(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX); 
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I get this result

```
0.314774
0.314774
0.314774
0.314774
```

But when I move the `srand` outside of the loop I get different random numers

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
main() 
{ 
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){  
        printf("%f\n",(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX); 
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I get these results

```
0.154158
0.832643
0.529257
0.529633
```

Answer (score -3):

If you see it with `time(NULL)` I believe it will always be close to each other because time is slowly incrementing.  You'll see your random number change slightly with the passing of time.

<s>Try this:</s>

```
(double)srand(time(NULL))/(double)RAND_MAX.
```

*--------EDIT--------*

Looks like my original assumption was wrong.  I ran this an get very different random numbers without reseeding.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <time.h>  

int main(void)
{
  int i, p;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for(p=0;p<10;p++){  
     i = rand();

     printf ("Your random number is %d\n", i);  

  }
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't necessarily follow.  Nearby seeds don't necessarily translate into nearby random numbers.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Correct, but I think he is seeding only once.  Instead of seeding each random number fetch.  This is just an assumption though, he didnt post enough code.

Comment: Well, it **was** working right, and generally `srand(time(NULL))` is the right way of creating random numbers.

Comment: If you seed the PRNG once with `175876342` and another time with `175876343` (the previous value + 1) the values generated have no relation to one another. see http://ideone.com/REgFm

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur: seeding the PRNG only once is the correct way to work with it.

Comment: This is my code, which generates all distinct random numbers, BUT which are all very close to eachother, slowly incrementing. `#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("%f",(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
}`

Comment: `srand` seeds the generator, it doesn't return a value.

Comment: @ClausW: You should capture the value of `time(NULL)`, and print that out as well.  Then someone else here may be able to recreate the problem.

Comment: time(NULL) is now 1332541636 but it is incrementing with 1/second.

Comment: @clausW can you post all of your code into your original post?

Comment: @ClausW: See this test-case: http://ideone.com/vk8it.  I get the same output running on GCC 4.1.2 as well.  What output does this code give when you compile and run it locally?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth   0.962897
0.962905
0.962913
0.962920

Comment: @ClausW: If that's the case, then something is very broken with your compiler (or its standard library implementation).